# Имея относительный адрес в памяти, как найти соответствующие ему логический и физический адреса? (память страничная)

Tags: память, ос, адрес

Вопрос от начинающего вкатываться в айти и программирование.

По заданию требуется найти логический и физический адреса по имеющемуся относительному адресу.
Относительный адрес, к примеру, 2211 (то бишь 1000 1010 0011). Размер страницы, соответственно, 512 байт, длина адреса у нас - 16 бит.

Если я правильно понял теорию, относительный адрес есть смещение внутри страницы, ведь так? Тогда для составления логического адреса необходим также номер адресуемой страницы. Выходит, для выполнения задания недостаточно данных?

Comment: Относительный адрес он относительно чего-то. Относительно чего он у вас?

Comment: В задании не указано. А относительно чего он может быть, кроме адреса начала сегмента/страницы? Гугление на эту тему мне не особо помогло.

Comment: Ну например RVA он относительно ImageBase. Адрес еще вполне может быть относительно начала секции. А вот захочу - скажу про относительно начала инструкции...

Comment: В задании сказано просто - "Найти логический и физический адреса по имеющемуся относительному адресу", и даны адреса, например 2211. Потому оно мне слегка ломает мозг, но, может, я чего-то недопонял по теории адресации в памяти.

Comment: Наверное, подразумевается некая система адресации...

Comment: Задание это, к слову, из практической работы чисто по основам страничной организации памяти. Насколько я понял, штудируя разные источники, логический адрес в страничной памяти должен состоять из номера страницы и смещения. Если дано только смещение, то как же составить логический адрес... непонятно.